# disable/enable for multiple buttons in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How to disable / enable Primefaces Buttons() so that if 1st is enabled then other two would be disabled and vice versa.

Comment: Show us your code for that buttons. That's not hard, and there are a lot of ways to do this. But it would be nice if you show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=JSF%20%2b%20partial%20%2b%20ajax%20%2b%20submit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a). It's called partial ajax submit, and it is used to send back to the server only updates on the relevant components involved in a request.